# glib.h cannot be found

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, glib

I have a problem when compiling my C program
This problem appears when i move frum ubunto 11 to ubunto 13.

When i compile with this makefile:

> gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-
>
> linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ -lglib-2.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -g -Wall
>
> -Wextra -std=c99 -lm *.c -o formattage

I get this error:

> main.c:5:18: erreur fatale: glib.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
> compilation terminée.

Glib2 Dev is installed on my machine but when i check /usr/lib/glib-2.0/include this file, i didn't find it

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not an expert of Linux and glib, is there a release version and a development version of that library, and perhaps you got the first one - which could come with files for program execution (shared libs, etc) but without headers files?

Comment: What do you see when you run `dpkg -L libglib2.0-dev | grep glib.h`?

Comment: When i run dpkg -L libglib2.0-dev | grep glib.h I GET this :::   /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h

Answer (score 3):

As you have the development package installed you should use the correct way to compile a program linking with Glib, which is to use `pkg-config` to get the correct values for your system.

If you change you Makefile to something like:

```
gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -lm *.c -o formattage `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```

then it will find the correct files.

Different systems and architectures install the files in different places, and to allow you to install multiple versions of Glib the files get placed in special directories. Using `pkg-config` solves this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you look on packages.ubuntu.com it looks like the file is in a different folder

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h    libglib2.0-dev
```

Is the header file at that path?

Comment: Sorry I was concentrating on the part where he said it's not at /usr/lib/glib-2.0/include

Comment: Ok, i try this command ::   gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ -lglib-2.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -lm *.c -o formattage         BUT always the same problem

Comment: Just tell us first if the header file is at the path above or not. And if the package libglib2.0-dev is installed. Your previous command was was fine.

Comment: Ok, here is not the same error :   gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include
cc1: warning: /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h: not a directory [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccHvXi7J.o: dans la fonction « hashSeqFct »:
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Formattage32/main.c:16: référence vers « g_str_hash »
/tmp/ccHvXi7J.o: dans la fonction « eqSeqFct »:
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Formattage32/main.c:24: référence indéfinie vers « g_hash_table_lookup »
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Formattage32/main.c:251: référence indéfinie vers « g_hash_table_lookup »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Erreur 1

Comment: Now you have a linking error which is progress I guess. Are you sure you still have the `-lglib-2.0` flag. Instead of specifying all the include and linking things by hand you might also try to use `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` as suggested by @iain

Comment: @user1117884 Okay, i try this "gcc pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -lm *.c -o formattage" but the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `libglib2.0-dev` package installed, since that's what provides the `glib.h` header.

Library packages (such as `libglib2.0-0`) typically only contain the compiled libraries for use by programs that have already been compiled.  To compile *new* programs using the associated library, you need to install the associated `-dev` package, which contains the library's header files.